Specify longitudinal hierarchical generalized additive model (HGAMM)
Data: Subject measurements across two sessions (pre, post). Each measurement has 50 interrelated values across location.
Example:
subj_id | session | location | value
1         pre       1          0.1
1         pre       2          0.12
..
1         pre       50         0.08
2         pre       1          0.04
..
30        post      50         0.12

Interest: Quantify effect of session on values, holding the global smooth constant. Plot of representative data, with the hypothesized effect near location 25:

Question: Have I correctly specified the model so that I'm pooling subject variance across session? The closest example I can find is this one. The paper by Pedersen et al. (2019) has been very (very) helpful.
# Longitudinal model, with global and session smooths
fit_GSL <- bam(
  value ~ s(subj_id, session, bs = "re") +
    s(location, bs = "tp", k=50) +
    s(location, session, bs = "fs", k = 50),
  data = df_long,
  family = betar(link = "logit"),
  method = "fREML",
  discrete = TRUE
)

This seems to work, giving me global and session smooths, but have I accounted for sessions occurring within subject?


Script to simulate data and specify model:
library("ggplot2")
library("fitdistrplus")
library("mgcv")
library("itsadug")

gen_norm <- function(y_scale, n = 50, mean = 1, sd = 0.1) {
  # Return normal distribution of values scaled by y_scale.
  h_min <- mean - (2.5 * sd)
  h_max <- mean + (2.5 * sd)
  h_seq <- seq(h_min, h_max, length = n)
  set.seed(y_scale)
  dist_out <- y_scale * dnorm(h_seq, mean, sd) + rnorm(n, 0, (0.15 * y_scale))
  return(dist_out)
}

# Plan subjects and number of values, scale
# the sessions differently
set.seed(12)
num_val <- 50
num_subj <- 60
subj_id <- 100 + seq(1:num_subj)
scale_pre <- runif(num_subj, 1, 3)
scale_post <- runif(num_subj, 2, 5)

# Start df
df_long <- as.data.frame(matrix(NA, nrow = 2 * num_subj * num_val, 
                                ncol = 4))
colnames(df_long) <- c("subj_id", "session", "location", "value")
df_long$subj_id <- rep(rep(subj_id, each = num_val), each = 2)
df_long$session <- rep(rep(c("Pre", "Post"), each = num_val), 2)
df_long$location <- rep(seq(1, num_val), 2 * num_subj)

# Fill df with generated values, adjust values to expected range
df_long <- df_long[order(df_long$session, decreasing = T), ]
c_start <- 1
for (h_seed in c(scale_pre, scale_post)) {
  c_end <- c_start + num_val - 1
  df_long[c_start:c_end, ]$value <- gen_norm(h_seed)
  c_start <- c_end + 1
}
df_long$value <- (df_long$value / 100) + 0.3

# Manage column types
df_long$subj_id <- factor(df_long$subj_id)
df_long$session <- factor(df_long$session)

# Plot data
ggplot(data = df_long, 
       aes(x = location, y = value, colour = session)) +
  facet_wrap(~ session) +
  geom_point(size = 1, alpha = 0.3) +
  theme(legend.position = "none") +
  labs(x = "Location", y = "Value") +
  ggtitle("Simulated Group Tracts") +
  theme(
    text = element_text(family = "Times New Roman")
  )

# Longitudinal model, with global and session smooths
descdist(df_long$value, discrete = FALSE)
fit_GSL <- bam(
  value ~ s(subj_id, session, bs = "re") +
    s(location, bs = "tp", k=50) +
    s(location, session, bs = "fs", k = 50),
  data = df_long,
  family = betar(link = "logit"),
  method = "fREML",
  discrete = TRUE
)
gam.check(fit_GSL)
plot(fit_GSL)

